# Implementing Binomial DIstribution in JavaScript error?

Tags: javascript, probability

I'm just hoping someone could double check my implementations to make sure everything is correct on the math and JS sides. I'm wondering where my implementation went wrong b/c the formulas do not compute the same probabilities, specifically *probability_three* seems to have a computation error I cannot find.

Here's the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/s73Lh1fk/5/

There are 3 functions I'm hoping to get reviewed.

1. probability_one
2. probability_two
3. probability_three

The formulas are as follows.

1. P(d, n) = 1 - (d - 1 / d)^n
2. P(d, n, o) = 1 - (d - (d - o + 1) / d)^n
3. P(d, n, o, k) = nCk * (p * k) * q^(n−k)

for nCk, I implemented https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/discretemathematics/combinations.php

```
function factorialize(num) {
// Step 1. Create a variable result to store num
var result = num;
 
// If num = 0 OR num = 1, the factorial will return 1
if (num === 0 || num === 1) 
    return 1; 

// Instatiate the while loop
while (num > 1) {
    // Decrement by 1 
    num--
    // Update the result
    result *= num
}
// Return
return result;
}

function nCr(n, r){
// Compute n factorial
var nFact = factorialize(n)
// Compute r factorial
var rFact = factorialize(r)
// Compute n - r factorial
var nrFact = factorialize(n - r)
// Compute nCr
var result = (nFact / (rFact * nrFact))
// Return
return result
}
```

If you need any more information, please don't hesitate to ask. I'll do my best to provide it.

For example:

The result here is 9.75%
[image: The result here is 9.75%]

```
function probability_one() {
// Get number of dice
var n = document.getElementById("n1").value
// Get sides on each die
var d = document.getElementById("d1").value
// Calculate
var prob = 1 - ((d - 1) / d)**n
prob = parseFloat(prob*100).toFixed(2)+"%"
prob = `<B>${prob}</B>`
// Print the probability
var p = document.createElement('p')
p.innerHTML = prob
document.getElementById("output1").appendChild(p)
}
```

The result here is 9.75%
[image: The result here is 9.75%]

```
function probability_two() {
// Get number of dice
var n = document.getElementById("n2").value
// Get sides on each die
var d = document.getElementById("d2").value
// Get the specific outcome
var o = document.getElementById("o2").value
// Calculate
var prob = 1 - ((d - (d - o + 1)) / d)**n
prob = parseFloat(prob*100).toFixed(2)+"%"
prob = `<B>${prob}</B>`
// Print the probability
var p = document.createElement('p')
p.innerHTML = prob
document.getElementById("output2").appendChild(p)
}
```

The result here is 18.00%, not 9.75%
[image: The result here is 18.00%, not 9.75%]

```
function probability_three(){
// USER INPUTS
    // Get number of dice
    var n = document.getElementById("n3").value
    // Get sides on each die
    var d = document.getElementById("d3").value
    // Get the value that defines a success
    var o = document.getElementById("o3").value
    // Get the number of success needed
    var k = document.getElementById("k3").value
// CALCULATIONS
    // p
    var p = ((d - o) + 1)/10
    console.log(`p: ${p}`)
    // q
    var q = (1 - p)
    console.log(`q: ${q}`)
    // nCr
    var vnCr = nCr(n, k)
    console.log(`nCr: ${vnCr}`)
    // p**k
    var pk = p**k
    console.log(`p**k: ${pk}`)
    // q**n-k
    var pnk = q**(n-k)
    console.log(`q**n-k: ${pnk}`)
    // Probability
    var prob = (vnCr * pk * pnk) / (p + q)**n
    console.log(`Prob.: ${prob}`)
    prob = parseFloat(prob*100).toFixed(2)+"%"
    prob = `<B>${prob}</B>`
// Print the probability
var p = document.createElement('p')
p.innerHTML = prob
document.getElementById("output3").appendChild(p)
}
```

Comment: remember that all `document.getElementById(...).value` are strings, make sure they are converted to numbers before computing the formulas.

Comment: My first guess is that your combinations function is getting messed up because the factorials are too big to fit into a float. Does the function work correctly for small numbers? Maybe try the exact calculation for small numbers and then fall back on Stirling's formula (for factorials) or some other approximation for larger numbers.

Comment: @RobertDodier , yeah, it works, but the issue arises when comparing it to the results of `probability_two()`. They're only consistent when n = 1. I'm wondering if `probability_two()` is suffering from rounding issues...

Comment: I don't see any obvious problems; it seems like the general approach should work for small numbers. My advice at this point is to break down each problem into pieces and verify each piece. For example the calculation of combinations is important. Try to verify that your combinations function is working right. That probably means verifying your factorial first. Try to work on each part (I mean parts one, two , and three) separately.